# Connecting to Internet using another system's proxy in same network

Tags: proxy, firefox

I don't know exactly I can do this or not, this is my scenario :

There are two computers on a same network, one with windows8 and me ( CentOS ) .

The one with windows8 is using proxy to connect to internet, and I dont have any software to do that . and I have to use proxy , because of internet filtering in my country .

So, I want to use that system to connect to internet by proxy .

I set my proxy IP and port to ***192.168.1.101:9666*** ( user's local IP ),and the proxy server's port ( like in his browser's setting ).

I tried that and Im getting this error : **The proxy server is refusing connections**

is it right? Can I do this like that? What I missed ?

by the way, my browser is firefox .

Comment: Are you even running proxy server software on the machine with the IP address `192.168.1.101`? Just because that machine is *using* a proxy server doesn't mean a second computer can access it as a proxy server.

Comment: the Ultrasurf software is running on that machine

Answer (score 1):

You can configure 1 machine running TOR proxy as a gateway for other devices on your network.  This is useful if you can change the proxy settings on device but you cannot install the TOR software itself.

Edit your `torrc` in `%appdata%\tor\`
Change the `SocksListenAddress` to the machines IP address.

`SocksListenAddress 192.168.1.101`

Next allow connections from your local network. Restart TOR after making these changes.

`SocksPolicy accept 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: can you  give more details ? how exactly I should do that?

Comment: Did you locate your `torrc` file? [Info](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#torrc) on the project's website.

Comment: the machine is not running tor, its running ultrasurf